# form_multiselect gives only one option

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry, but this is kind a homework question...

I have to make a webpage with codeigniter and I have to use multiple select component.

So my code.

Part in `*view.php` file:

```
<br>Keywords:<br>
<?php echo form_multiselect('keywords', $keys); ?>
```

Also there is submit button, and after it pressed I take POST data. For debugging tried:

```
var_dump($_POST['keywords']);
```

This always shows, that there is only one option selected, for example, `string(1) "2"`

Can someone advice how should I modify my code to get all selected items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
<?php echo form_multiselect('keywords[]', $keys); ?>
```

A multiselect form field must have a name with array notation.

You would expect codeignitors function to accommodate this, but it doesnt (well not when i last used CI in 2010)

Answer (score 2):

From the Codeigniter documentation:

> form_multiselect()
>
> Lets you create a standard multiselect field. The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the value or values you wish to be selected. The parameter usage is identical to using form_dropdown() above, except of course that the name of the field will need to use POST array syntax, e.g. foo[].

The last sentence states you need to use POST array syntax, so the name of the select should be, in your case

```
name="keywords[]"
```